# Remote download with JavaScript with a custom file name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file, download

I have a page on my website which has a button, that redirects to a URL, that downloads the source code of the git repo for that website. Here is the HTML I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p>Would you like to download this website's source code?</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://codeload.github.com/SteepAtticStairs/steepatticstairs.github.io/zip/refs/heads/main'">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = '/index.html'">No</button>
</body>

</html>
```

However, this downloads a file with the name `steepatticstairs.github.io-main.zip`. I have a bash script that I wrote:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

url=https://codeload.github.com/SteepAtticStairs/steepatticstairs.github.io/zip/refs/heads/main
now="$(date '+%m.%d.%Y')"


cd ~/Downloads

wget -O "steepatticstairs.github.io_${now}.zip" $url
```

Which downloads the file with a name like `steepatticstairs.github.io_03.09.2022.zip`. This is the name that I want - with the date at the end.

Is there any way that I could replicate this in JavaScript, perhaps using jQuery, where I could click the `Yes` button and it would download the file from the URL, but it would rename it before download? If someone is able to quickly show me how to also get the date into the filename in JavaScript, that would be awesome, but I would be able to figure that out. I just want to know how to rename the file before downloading.

Answer (score 1):

because cross-domain the ajax will blocked by CORS policy，you need the server to proxy the request and modify the Content-Disposition in the response header, for example: `Content-Disposition:attachment;filename= ${filename}.zip`

<s>you can use ajax to download file:</s>

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = '${filename}.zip';
    a.click()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
});
// if need progress bar can listen progress event
// xhr.addEventListener('progress', e => console.log(e.loaded/e.total))
xhr.open('GET', '${url}')
xhr.send()
```

Comment: is it possible you could show me how to use that javascript in my HTML above? I try to add all of that code under a function and then call that function with `onclick`, but it attempts to redirect me to a page called "undefined" in that directory. I am working in a directory called `/random/`, and it is trying to redirect me to `/random/undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the situation of cross-domain，if change `${url}` to github, request will blocked by CORS policy